# Populating a TreeMap throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, treemap

I am getting a NullPointerException while creating a TreeMap.

Here is my code:

```
public TreeMap<AccountGroupBean,List<AccountBean>> getAccountsAndGroups() throws SessionExpiredException {
    TreeMap<AccountGroupBean,List<AccountBean>> map = new TreeMap<AccountGroupBean,List<AccountBean>>();
    List<AccountGroupBean> groups = getAccountGroups();
    for(AccountGroupBean group : groups) {
        List<AccountBean> accounts = getAccountsByGroupId(group.getId());
        System.out.println("PRINT"+ accounts.size());           
        map.put(group,accounts);
        System.out.println("!" +map.get(group).size());
    }
    return map;
}
```

The first println prints 44. That it is to say is not null. However, the second println raises the null exception.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

## Solution

AS pointed in the accepted solution. The problem was in my implementation of compareTo.

I used to have:

```
public int compareTo(AccountGroupBean o) {
    return (number > o.getNumber()) ? 1 : -1;       
}
```

Adding a 0 return solved the issue:

```
public int compareTo(AccountGroupBean o) {
    if(number == o.getNumber()) {
         return 0;
    }
    return (number > o.getNumber()) ? 1 : -1;       
}
```

Comment: stacktrace would be helpful...

Comment: Does `AccountGroupBean` override `hashcode()` and `equals()`?

Comment: Have you simplified your code sample for SO, and removed something critical? The specific thing I can think of is a custom Comparator in the TreeMap constructor, and it is the Comparator which is falling over on the get but not on the put?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looks like `AccountGroupBean` doesn't implement `Comparable` in a proper way, try to println `group.compareTo(group)` to check if it prints `0`.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a problem with how the AccountGroupBean class is implementing equals and hashcode. There are some rules fro implementing equals and hashcode that you should make sure your code complies to. Some of the rules for the equals method include.

- **Reflexive** for any non null value `x.equals(x)` is always true
- **Symetric** for non null values `y.equals(x)` must return true if and only if `x.equals(y)` is true
- **Transitive** for non null values if `x.equals(y)` is true and `y.equals(z)` is true then `x.equals(z)` must also be true
- **Consistant** The equals method should return the same answer during multiple invocations if the objects have not been modfied.
- If two objects are equal their hashcoe method should return the same value.

Comment: @Sergio, no unless you want to consider several instances of the AccountGroupBean as equals for example new AccountGroupBean(1).equals(new AccountGroupBean(1)) will be false unless you implement equals , and if you implement equals you should also implement hashcode consistently...

Comment: This is useful information, but TreeMap relies on compareTo rather than on hashcode and equals like a hashmap...

Comment: @pgras +1 you are right. I did not know this. I always thought that compareTo was just used on insert for sortinging purposes. You learn something new everyday.